# Integration Testing Stripe Payments - stripe-mock or Stripe's test mode?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing, payment

I'm building an automated test suite to integration/feature test my organization's [Stripe](https://stripe.com) implementation within a GitLab CI pipeline. We're running Laravel 8 and using phpunit for testing.

Within this suite I'm testing both happy and non-happy paths (i.e. I want to test valid *and invalid* payment details).

At the moment the suite is just running locally and is using a Stripe account that dedicated for testing using Stripe's test mode. I've been using Stripe's [testing tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/testing) to create different types of payments and its all working good so far. However, I want the test suite to run quickly within a CI pipeline, and I found [stripe-mock](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock) as an alternative. stripe-mock claims it makes,

> test suites integrating with Stripe faster and less brittle.

However, stripe-mock notes that a current limitation is,

> Testing for specific responses and errors is currently not supported. It will return a success response instead of the desired error response.

So based on this I've got two questions:

1. **What is the use case of stripe-mock if it will always return a successful response regardless of the validity of the payment?**
2. **Is there another preferred way integration testing a Stripe implementation, or is what I'm currently doing the best approach?**

With regards to my second question I believe my options are to:

1. Keep using Stripe's test mode.
2. Build a happy-path suite using stripe-mock, and a non-happy-path suite using Stripe's test mode.
3. Build a happy-path suite using stripe-mock, and just manual test non-happy paths. ( I don't really see this as a valid option for me as I would like smoke tests for all Stripe related functionality)
4. Something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For future folks who find this thread, here's an example of how to setup your Rails test environment and use `stripe-ruby-mock` to test the Stripe API without accessing the production instance:

https://betterprogramming.pub/test-driven-development-with-stripe-and-ruby-on-rails-cfc81e3e261

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - one of the strong guidelines for answers here is that they should be [self-contained and not need readers to visit another site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Could you edit in the essential point from the linked site into your answer?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the use case of stripe-mock if it will always return a successful response regardless of the validity of the payment?

It reminds me of the time I pretended to mock up MongoDB. For the sake of the answer, I won't tell the story but believe me when I say I was too naive to believe it.

In my experience, I think `stripe-mock` can help you execute tests faster but not build confidence in your tests. You have to decide what your test should provide you with. If you ask me, *confidence > velocity* all the time.

That said, It doesn't mean I will give up on making test executions to be faster.

> Is there another preferred way of integration testing a Stripe implementation, or is what I'm currently doing the best approach?

Sure. Implement a Proxy and cache requests and responses. It might interest you: [Mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/proxies#proxy-modes)

How would I do it?

- Run a Mountebank container [enabling persistence to file](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/commandLine#start)
- Enable the proxy mode "proxyOnce"
- Tune up accurate `predicateGenerators`
- Set up integration tests to send requests to Mountebank instead of Stripe
- Execute Contract tests to record requests and Stripe responses.

  *Note: Don't test the whole API, only those features you need*
- Save the Mountebank configuration to a file I can version.
- Run all my tests

4th and 5th can be performed once in a while from a different pipeline (let's say daily overnight). The pipeline keeps stubs up-to-date and ensures the Mountebank server responds according to the current version of the Stripe API contract.